# Android: How to find duration of Marquee textview scroll duration

Tags: android, scroll, textview, duration

I'm using a textview in my app with marquee limit 1. After the first complete scrolling i want to update the textview content. For that i need to calculate the duration for one complete scrolling of textview. Is there any way to find the same. Please help me.

Thanks And Regards

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I have the same requirement. Please shed some light if you have come across a solution.

Comment: You can use animation instead of marquee where you can specify the duration of scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

use `getAnimation().getDuration()` to get marquee scroll duration
Try with the following code.

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview2);
long duration = textView.getAnimation().getDuration();
```

Comment: Hi, getAnimation() function returns null. Why?

Comment: @Unnikrishnan you are using the marquee option and not an animation, this is why it returns null.